# saving the form navigates to end of the crm form

Tags: dynamics-crm-2016

I am facing an issue in CRM 2016. I have a custom entity called shipment. when I update any field value and save the record it automatically scrolls down to the end of the page. Did any one faced the same issue? Please find me a solution for this. Not all the time this issue comes but most of the time. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the issue still happen if you remove all of your scripts from the form?

Comment: Does it happen in different browsers?

Comment: Tried to clear the browser cache?

Comment: Yes. I disabled all the script methods and also cleared cache. still same issue. what I noticed is, when I change only two option field then the issue reproduces. updating other fields is fine. Thanks!!